# windows tr -s equivalent

Tags: windows, command-line

In Linux, when I get (as a result of a command) several lines back and in every line there are multiple spaces between the char values, I use "tr -s ' '" (squeeze).

```
lsof | tr -s ''
```

Is there anything like that in the windows command line?

```
netstat -ano | ???
```

Thanks a lot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm, I'll avoid saying Windows is rubbish, and just refer you to UnixUtils which is simpler than cygwin and doesn't need much installation.

Get it [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the lazy way, by installing some bash environment.

For instance, Git installers for Windows provide you with a shell ("Git bash" menu) where you can find most of your usual GNU/Linux script commmands.
(and use netstat too)